# R '.doSnowGlobals' not found

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am working with the package random uniform Forest. I am trying to run the examples provided in the documentation:

```
data(iris)
XY = iris
p = ncol(XY)
X = XY[,-p]
Y = XY[,p]
iris.ruf = randomUniformForest(Species ~., XY, threads = 1)
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) : 
7 nodes produced errors; first error: object '.doSnowGlobals' not found
```

I googled and found that this is because it is trying to use paralell computing and it does not find something it needs. I have never used paralell computing so I did not understand the explanations I have found and I do not know how to fix this problem. I also read "[error: object '.doSnowGlobals' not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079527/error-object-dosnowglobals-not-found)".

According to the manual using "threads = 1" deactivated paralell computing, but I get the error anyways.

I have also checked and the packages paralell and doParallel are loaded.

I do not really need paralell computing and I do not know if I am "connected" to other computers, so I am not sure If that would even work. Would there be an easy way do deactivate paralell computing? Or another alternative for making this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the problem was that I was working on my university computer for which I do not have administrator rights. The randomUniformForest package makes use of parallel processing which uses the IP protocol (even when only one thread is used).

I tried the package on my private computer and it worked fine.