# How to set .libPaths (checkpoint) on workers when running parallel computation in R

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, checkpoint, r-future

I use the checkpoint package for reproducible data analysis. Some of the computations take a long time to compute, so I want to run those in parallel.
When run in parallel however the checkpoint is not set on the workers, so I get an error message **"there is no package called xy"** (because it is not installed in my default library directory).

How can I make sure, that each worker uses the package versions in the checkpoint folder? I tried to set .libPaths in the foreach code but this does not seem to work. I would also prefer to set the checkpoint/libPaths once globally and not in every foreach call.

Another option could be to change the .Rprofile file, but I do not want to do this.

```
checkpoint::checkpoint("2018-06-01")

library(foreach)
library(doFuture)
library(future)

doFuture::registerDoFuture()
future::plan("multisession")

l <- .libPaths()

# Code to run in parallel does not make much sense of course but I wanted to keep it simple.
res <- foreach::foreach(
  x = unique(iris$Species),
  lib.path = l
) %dopar% {
  .libPaths(lib.path)
  stringr::str_c(x, "_")
}
```

> Error in { : task 2 failed - "there is no package called 'stringr'"

Comment: Why don't you load `stringr` by `require` or `library` specifying the correct directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Author of the [**future**](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future) package here.

UPDATE 2022-05-25: As of **future** 1.20.0 (2021-11-03), **multisession** parallel workers automatically inherit the R library path (=`.libPaths()`) from the main R session. Because of this, the below workaround is no longer needed. However, it may still be needed for other future backends.

---

Passing the library path of the master R process as a global variable `libs` and set it for each worker using `.libPaths(libs)` should be enough;

```
## Use CRAN checkpoint from 2018-07-24 to get future (>= 1.9.0) [1],
## otherwise the below stdout won't be relayed back to the master
## R process, but settings .libPaths() does also work in older
## versions of the future package.
## [1] https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2018-07-24/web/packages/future
checkpoint::checkpoint("2018-07-24")
stopifnot(packageVersion("future") >= "1.9.0")

libs <- .libPaths()
print(libs)
### [1] "/home/hb/.checkpoint/2018-07-24/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.5.1"
### [2] "/home/hb/.checkpoint/R-3.5.1"                                 
### [3] "/usr/lib/R/library"

library(foreach)

doFuture::registerDoFuture()
future::plan("multisession")

res <- foreach::foreach(x = unique(iris$Species)) %dopar% {
  ## Use the same library paths as the master R session
  .libPaths(libs)
  
  cat(sprintf("Library paths used by worker (PID %d):\n", Sys.getpid()))
  cat(sprintf(" - %s\n", sQuote(.libPaths())))
      
  stringr::str_c(x, "_")
}

###  - ‘/home/hb/.checkpoint/2018-07-24/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.5.1’
###   - ‘/home/hb/.checkpoint/R-3.5.1’
###   - ‘/usr/lib/R/library’
### Library paths used by worker (PID 9394):
###  - ‘/home/hb/.checkpoint/2018-07-24/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.5.1’
###   - ‘/home/hb/.checkpoint/R-3.5.1’
###   - ‘/usr/lib/R/library’
### Library paths used by worker (PID 9412):
###  - ‘/home/hb/.checkpoint/2018-07-24/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.5.1’
###   - ‘/home/hb/.checkpoint/R-3.5.1’
###   - ‘/usr/lib/R/library’

str(res)
### List of 3
###  $ : chr "setosa_"
###  $ : chr "versicolor_"
###  $ : chr "virginica_"
```

FYI, it is on future's roadmap to [make it easier to pass down the library path(s) to workers](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/issues/219).

My details:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)   
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)   
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS   

Matrix products: default   
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1   
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1   
  
locale:   
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8           LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                     LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C          
  
attached base packages:   
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base        
  
other attached packages:   
[1] foreach_1.4.4   
  
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):   
[1] drat_0.1.4         compiler_3.5.1     BiocManager_1.30.2 parallel_3.5.1        tools_3.5.1        listenv_0.7.0      doFuture_0.6.0    
[8] codetools_0.2-15   iterators_1.0.10   digest_0.6.15      globals_0.12.1        checkpoint_0.4.5   future_1.9.0
```

Comment: Thanks. Looking forward to the new option `plan(multisession, libs = .libPaths())`, this would be great

Comment: I could also run `Sys.setenv(R_LIBS = paste(.libPaths()[1], Sys.getenv("R_LIBS"), sep = .Platform$path.sep))` after running `checkpoint` right? Because it is easier to run this once at the beginning of the script, then to rewrite functions in existing R packages to pass `.libPaths` in every foreach call.

Comment: @needRhelp, yes, setting env var `R_LIBS` before calling `plan(multisession)` will cause that env var to be recognized by the startup process of each background workers.  **However**, you also need to unset `R_LIBS_USER` and `R_LIBS_SITE` and you need to make sure that neither of those is set in an `.Renviron` startup file.  If not, then you're library path will _not_ be the same as `.libPaths()` of the master R session.  This is why I proposed the `.libPaths(libs)` approach.  I hope to come up with a cleaner solution as part of the future package at some point.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! When trying to use your answer I had a follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53117396/internal-function-of-r-package-not-found-when-using-foreach-with-checkpoint. Can you help me with this?