# mlr / parallelMap: How to pass libPaths to workers when working with checkpoint?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mlr

This is basically the same question as this [How to set .libPaths (checkpoint) on workers when running parallel computation in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52276088/how-to-set-libpaths-checkpoint-on-workers-when-running-parallel-computation-i), but now addressing parallelization of mlr model fits. I understand that I need to use `parallelMap` with `mlr`, but how can I make sure that each worker uses the correct `.libPaths`?

```
remove.packages("mlr")
remove.packages("rpart")

checkpoint::checkpoint("2018-09-01",
                       scanForPackages = TRUE)

library(mlr)
library(parallelMap)
library(rpart)
parallelStartSocket(2L)

task = makeClassifTask(data = iris, target = "Species")
learner = makeLearner("classif.rpart", minsplit = 7, predict.type = "prob")
mod = resample(learner, task, resampling = cv5)

parallelStop()
```

> Error in parallelLibrary("mlr", master = FALSE, level =
>   "mlr.resample",  :    Packages could not be loaded on all slaves: mlr.

Session info:

> R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252 
>   LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 [4]
>   LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1] rpart_4.1-13      parallelMap_1.3
>   mlr_2.13          ParamHelpers_1.11
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] Rcpp_0.12.18
>   pillar_1.3.0      compiler_3.5.1    plyr_1.8.4        bindr_0.1.1
>   tools_3.5.1        [7] tibble_1.4.2      gtable_0.2.0
>   checkmate_1.8.5   lattice_0.20-35   pkgconfig_2.0.2   rlang_0.2.2
>   [13] Matrix_1.2-14     fastmatch_1.1-0   rstudioapi_0.7    yaml_2.2.0 
>   parallel_3.5.1    bindrcpp_0.2.2    [19] dplyr_0.7.6       grid_3.5.1 
>   tidyselect_0.2.4  glue_1.3.0        data.table_1.11.4 R6_2.2.2
>   [25] XML_3.98-1.16     survival_2.42-3   ggplot2_3.0.0     purrr_0.2.5
>   magrittr_1.5      backports_1.1.2   [31] scales_1.0.0      BBmisc_1.11
>   splines_3.5.1     assertthat_0.2.0  checkpoint_0.4.3  colorspace_1.3-2
>   [37] stringi_1.1.7     lazyeval_0.2.1    munsell_0.5.0
>   crayon_1.3.4

Comment: The code you've posted works fine for me.

Comment: Ok, let me explain this in more detail. `checkpoint` changes the path where R searches for installed packages. I have installed the packages in the checkpoint folder, so the code will run fine if not parallelized. But when the code is run in parallel fresh R sessions are started where .libPaths is not the checkpoint path, but the default library path. So it looks in a different folder for R packages where I don't have these packages installed, so it raises an error. If you remove mlr from your default libPaths folder you should see the same error. Hope that makes it clear

Comment: Can you post code that allows to reproduce the error please?

Comment: The code is reproducible. I have added the session info in case that it is something platform dependent.

Comment: I have run the code you've posted and I do not get the error.

Comment: No experience with the checkpoint package but wouldn't it be easiest to use a packrat library? That's how I ensure that a specific R lib is used and it works when parallelizing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but sadly this is not an alternative in my situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me if I change the default library path to the checkpoint directory with R_LIBS.

```
remove.packages("mlr")
remove.packages("rpart")

print(.libPaths())
checkpoint::checkpoint("2018-09-01",
                       scanForPackages = TRUE)
print(.libPaths())
Sys.setenv(R_LIBS = paste(.libPaths()[1], Sys.getenv("R_LIBS"), sep = .Platform$path.sep))

library(mlr)
library(parallelMap)
library(rpart)
parallelStartSocket(2L)

task = makeClassifTask(data = iris, target = "Species")
learner = makeLearner("classif.rpart", minsplit = 7, predict.type = "prob")
mod = resample(learner, task, resampling = cv5)

parallelStop()
```