# Internal function of R package not found when using foreach with checkpoint

Tags: r, r-future

This is a follow-up question of this question: [How to set .libPaths (checkpoint) on workers when running parallel computation in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52276088/how-to-set-libpaths-checkpoint-on-workers-when-running-parallel-computation-i)

Based on the answer I put the following code (simplified example) into an R package called 'test1':

```
#' @export
f <- function() {
  `%dopar%` <- foreach::`%dopar%`
  doFuture::registerDoFuture()
  libs <- .libPaths()

  res <- foreach::foreach(x = 1:2) %dopar% {

    cat(sprintf("Initial Library paths used by worker (PID %d):\n", Sys.getpid()))
    cat(sprintf(" - %s\n", sQuote(.libPaths()[1])))

    ## Use the same library paths as the master R session
    .libPaths(libs)

    cat(sprintf("Library paths used by worker (PID %d):\n", Sys.getpid()))
    cat(sprintf(" - %s\n", sQuote(.libPaths()[1])))

    x + g()
  }

  res
}


g <- function() {
  h()
}

h <- function() {
  runif(1)
}
```

Then I called `checkpoint::checkpoint("2018-07-24")` and installed the package into the checkpoint library. The following code then produced this error:

```
checkpoint::checkpoint("2018-07-24")
future::plan("multisession")
test1::f()
```

> Initial Library paths used by worker (PID 16880):
>    - 'C:/Programme/R-3.5.1/library'
>
> Library paths used by worker (PID 16880):
>    - '.../.checkpoint/2018-07-24/lib/x86_64-w64-mingw32/3.5.1'
>
> Initial Library paths used by worker (PID 3916):
>    - 'C:/Programme/R-3.5.1/library'
>
> Library paths used by worker (PID 3916):
>    - '.../.checkpoint/2018-07-24/lib/x86_64-w64-mingw32/3.5.1'
>
> Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "h""

When I explicitly call `test1:::g()` inside the `foreach` call, it works though. Can someone explain, why I have to explicitly call a function of my own package inside a foreach loop with `:::`? It looks like `g()` seems to be found, but `h()` then not?

Comment: Could you please set up a small online repository (e.g. on GitHub) contain a minimal R package that can be used to reproduce and troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: FYI, if you set `options(future.debug = TRUE)`, then you'll be able to what set of globals and packages the future package identifies and which globals are eventually exported and what packages are loaded.

Comment: @HenrikB You can find the code here https://github.com/markusdumke/test1